# C++ tolower/toupper char pointer

Tags: c++, toupper, tolower, char-pointer

Do you guys know why the following code crash during the runtime?

```
char* word;
word = new char[20];
word = "HeLlo"; 
for (auto it = word; it != NULL; it++){        
    *it = (char) tolower(*it);
```

I'm trying to lowercase a char* (string). I'm using visual studio.

Thanks

Comment: `new` is C++, not C.

Comment: you are using auto in the same time using char*.. search for std::string and you gonna have less time debugging and more time to enjoy

Comment: Did you overwrite the `word = new char[20];` allocation with `word = "HeLlo";`? If so, you cannot `delete word` later.

Comment: @HumamHelfawi  Thanks! just wanted to use char* instead of string.  Even when I use  `char* it` still get the runtime error.  @Weather yes.

Comment: You also forgot to free the memory you allocated, which is a very common and serious mistake.

Comment: You are (re)assigning a pointer to memory to point to a constant literal.  The expression `word = "Hello";` **assigns a pointer and does not copy contents.**  Use `std::string` instead.

Comment: If you want to use a pointer (why?) instead of the `string` class, you need to understand the semantic of pointers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot compare `it` to `NULL`. Instead you should be comparing `*it` to `'\0'`. Or better yet, use `std::string` and never worry about it :-)

In summary, when looping over a C-style string. You should be looping until the **character** you see is a `'\0'`. The iterator itself will never be `NULL`, since it is simply pointing a place in the string. The fact that the iterator has a type which can be compared to `NULL` is an implementation detail that you shouldn't touch directly.

Additionally, you are trying to write to a string literal. Which is a no-no :-).

**EDIT**:
As noted by @Cheers and hth. - Alf, `tolower` can break if given negative values. So sadly, we need to add a cast to make sure this won't break if you feed it Latin-1 encoded data or similar.

This should work:

```
char word[] = "HeLlo";
for (auto it = word; *it != '\0'; ++it) {
    *it = tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(*it));
}
```

Comment: Better fix the call to `tolower`, since presumably this example is intended to show off generally correct code

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, fair enough. I'll add something for that :-)

Answer (score 4):

You're setting `word` to point to the string literal, but literals are read-only, so this results in undefined behavior when you assign to `*it`. You need to make a copy of it in the dynamically-allocated memory.

```
char *word = new char[20];
strcpy(word, "HeLlo");
```

Also in your loop you should compare `*it != '\0'`. The end of a string is indicated by the character being the null byte, not the pointer being null.

Answer (score 3):

Given code (as I'm writing this):

```
char* word;
word = new char[20];
word = "HeLlo"; 
for (auto it = word; it != NULL; it++){        
    *it = (char) tolower(*it);
```

This code has **Undefined Behavior** in 2 distinct ways, and would have UB also in a third way if only the text data was slightly different:

- Buffer overrun.
  The continuation condition `it != NULL` will not be `false` until the pointer `it` has wrapped around at the end of the address range, if it does.
- Modifying read only memory.
  The pointer `word` is set to point to the first `char` of a string literal, and then the loop iterates over that string and assigns to each `char`.
- Passing possible negative value to `tolower`.
  The `char` classification functions require a non-negative argument, or else the special value `EOF`. This works fine with the string `"HeLlo"` under an assumption of ASCII or unsigned `char` type. But in general, e.g. with the string `"Blåbærsyltetøy"`, directly passing each `char` value to `tolower` will result in negative values being passed; a correct invocation with `ch` of type `char` is `(char) tolower( (unsigned char)ch )`.

Additionally the code has a **memory leak**, by allocating some memory with `new` and then just forgetting about it.

A correct way to code the apparent intent:

```
using Byte = unsigned char;

auto to_lower( char const c )
    -> char
{ return Byte( tolower( Byte( c ) ) ); }

// ...
string word = "Hello";
for( char& ch : word ) { ch = to_lower( ch ); }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already two nice answers on how to solve your issues using null terminated c-strings and poitners.  For the sake of completeness, I propose you an approach using c++ strings:

```
string word;           // instead of char* 
//word = new char[20]; // no longuer needed: strings take care for themseves
word = "HeLlo";        //  no worry about deallocating previous values: strings take care for themselves
for (auto &it : word)  // use of range for, to iterate through all the string elements      
    it = (char) tolower(it);
```

Comment: Better fix the call to `tolower`, since presumably this example is intended to show off generally correct code. Also, I would fix the naming. `it` is not an iterator.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf well, for the more general case, I'd go for `it = (char)tolower(it, loc);` where loc is a locale

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. It just adds verbosity, inefficiency and complexity (for making the locale available). In contrast, the C function is simple, reasonably efficient, and locale-aware.

Comment: If you're writing non localised english software, your're certainly right.  But for european charsets,  the mapping upper<->lower isn't quite the same for ascii (not defined) iso8859 (ex: 0xE4 ä 0xD4 Ä) and legacy iso646 (0x84 ä 0x8E Ä). Here the locale overhead is in fact a real benefit.

Comment: The C function **is** locale-aware. It uses the C level locale set with `setlocale`. I was not talking about a general locale overhead, I was talking about the overhead of involving C++ locales. Anyway note that it's not meaningful to draw a difference between Latin-1 (ISO 8859) and Unicode (ISO 646) in this context. Latin-1 is a strict subset of Unicode, it's the first 256 code points.

Answer (score 1):

Its crashing because you are modifying a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

there is a dedicated functions for this
use 
`strupr` for making string uppercase and `strlwr` for making the string lower case.

here is an usage example:

```
char str[ ] = "make me upper";
printf("%s\n",strupr(str));


char str[ ] = "make me lower";
printf("%s\n",strlwr (str));
```